# What does "一連覇中" mean?

Tags: translation

From this article: https://baseballking.jp/ns/75506

> 日本一連覇中の王者でありながら

What is the meaning and purpose of 一連覇中 here? Does it mean he became champion multiples?

Won't 日本の王者 just mean the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such a word as 一連覇 or 一連覇中. It's parsed like `日本一` + `(連覇 + 中)`.

- **日本一【にほんいち】**: (Japan's) number one; being a champion (in Japan)
- **連覇**: straight victory; successive winning
- **-中(の)**: in the middle of ～

> 日本一連覇中の王者でありながら
> despite being a reigning champion winning multiple times in a row

日本の王者 does not have the meaning of 連覇中 ("currently winning in a row").